# GA4 tracks value of purchase but doesn't add up to Total Revenue

Tags: google-analytics, event-tracking, google-analytics-4, google-datalayer

As you can see GA4 clearly doesn't show revenue:

[image: GA4 Total Revenue]

However, when I go to **Configure-> Conversions** I can clearly see that it does track the value:

[image: Purchase Value]

Our data layer looks as followed:

```
{
  event: "purchase",
  gtm: {uniqueEventId: 7, start: 1541254301557},
  ecommerce: {
    transaction_id: "TEST000000184",
    affiliation: "Brand Name B2C - Brand Name B2C website - Brand Name English",
    value: "36.0000",
    coupon: "",
    tax: "4.5100",
    shipping: "10.0000",
    items: [
      {
        item_name: "Plate 27cm green",
        item_id: "10000",
        item_price: "5.37",
        item_brand: "Brand Name",
        item_category: "",
        quantity: "4.0000"
      }
    ]
  }
```

Comment: This question does not apear to be programming related. It is about data shown on the Google analytics web app you may have better luck https://webapps.stackexchange.com/ or possibly https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 0):

Currency is a required parameter in your `ecommerce` object.

```
currency: "USD",
```

Also, you should keep your quantity as integers not floats

`quantity: "4"` not `quantity: "4.0000"`